# How to get the device name of a specified mount point with ansible facts?

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible facts I can get the list of "ansible_mounts":

```
        "ansible_mounts": [
            {
                "block_available": 423698, 
                "block_size": 4096, 
                "block_total": 507604, 
                "block_used": 83906, 
                "device": "/dev/sdb1", 
                "fstype": "ext4", 
                "inode_available": 130999, 
                "inode_total": 131072, 
                "inode_used": 73, 
                "mount": "/boot", 
                "options": "rw", 
                "size_available": 1735467008, 
                "size_total": 2079145984, 
                "uuid": "b5cfa485-21d2-4e66-b3a3-80f250acf9d9"
            }, 
            {
                "block_available": 42446481, 
                "block_size": 4096, 
                "block_total": 131007993, 
                "block_used": 88561512, 
                "device": "/dev/sdd1", 
                "fstype": "xfs", 
                "inode_available": 524243436, 
                "inode_total": 524287936, 
                "inode_used": 44500, 
                "mount": "/u01", 
                "options": "rw", 
                "size_available": 173860786176, 
                "size_total": 536608739328, 
                "uuid": "f34a9499-ca4e-4db6-801a-16efb72a629d"
            }, 
            {
                "block_available": 3010686, 
                "block_size": 4096, 
                "block_total": 4095466, 
                "block_used": 1084780, 
                "device": "/dev/sdc1", 
                "fstype": "ext4", 
                "inode_available": 984674, 
                "inode_total": 1048576, 
                "inode_used": 63902, 
                "mount": "/", 
                "options": "rw", 
                "size_available": 12331769856, 
                "size_total": 16775028736, 
                "uuid": "829e9504-965b-4660-acc2-12d10d022a3c"
            }
        ],
```

How I can get the value of `device` where `mount` value is "/" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-json-data-json-queries). For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_device: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query(query) }}"
      vars:
        query: "[?mount=='/'].device "
    - debug:
        var: my_device
```

gives

```yaml
    my_device:
      - /dev/sdc1
```

To get the first element of the list only append the filter [first](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.first)

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_device: "{{ ansible_mounts|json_query(query)|first }}"
```

Comment: to get only the value I should use `{{ my_device[0] }}`

Comment: Right. The result is a list because, generally, there might be more hits. It's also possible to append the filter ``{{ ansible_mounts|json_query(query)|first }}`` to get the first element of the list.